# Unable to display table rows based on criteria using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table `(id="tblID")` that is populated from database. The rows have a data attribute `status`, which can either be `"Y"` or `"N"` and only rows that have `"Y"` are to be shown on page load. Somewhere in the `$(document).ready()` there is this call: which is supposed to show the active rows on page load by passing `"Y"` to the `showRowsByStatus`:

```
$("#tblID tr").each(function () {
    showRowsByStatus("Y", $(this));
});
```

There is also checkbox `Show Inactive Rows` which when checked will show the inactive rows and when unchecked will show active rows.

```
$("#chkBox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#tblID tr").each(function () {
            showRowsByStatus("N", $(this));
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#tblID tr").each(function () {
            showRowsByStatus("Y", $(this));
        });
    }
});
```

This is the definition of `showRowsByStatus` method:

```
function showRowsByStatus(activeStatus, tr) {
    if (tr.data("status") == activeStatus && tr.data("status") != undefined) {
        tr.show();
    }
    if (tr.data("status") != activeStatus && tr.data("status") != undefined) {
        tr.hide();
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is, on page load active rows are not being displayed at all, but when I toggle the checkbox `Show Inactive Rows`, the rows are displayed as expected.

What am I missing in the `showRowsByStatus` method?

I also found that `style="display:none"` is being added to all rows when the page loads. I have checked every where in the project and I can't find anything that sets this style to these rows. I tried `.css("display","none !important")` for hiding and `.css("display","block !important")` for showing, but it didn't help. So I am thinking I should fix the `showRowsByStatus` method.

Comment: Seems like on load the Status for every row is "N". Please check or provide Fiddle for the same.

Comment: You say the data attribute is called `status` but are checking an attribute called `role` - is this correct?

Comment: I corrected the above code. Correct variable is `status`.

Comment: I don't know why you getting an error. I recreated your code and it works fine...so may be it's where the code is put. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working fine and I changed nothing in your jQuery code. May be related to your HTML code around it. You can try it there : http://seo035.com/test/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test Inactive Row</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#tblID tr").each(function () {
        showRowsByStatus("Y", $(this));
    });

    $("#chkBox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#tblID tr").each(function () {
                showRowsByStatus("N", $(this));
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#tblID tr").each(function () {
                showRowsByStatus("Y", $(this));
            });
        }
    });      
 })

function showRowsByStatus(activeStatus, tr) {
    if (tr.data("status") == activeStatus && tr.data("status") != undefined) {
        tr.show();
    }
    if (tr.data("status") != activeStatus && tr.data("status") != undefined) {
        tr.hide();
    }
}

</script>
<table id="tblID">
<tr data-status="Y"><td>Row Y</td></tr>
<tr data-status="N"><td>Row N</td></tr>
</table>
<form>
<input id="chkBox" type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fabien, thanks for verifying this for me and confirming that it works just fine. This forced me to look at other things and found something that is possible cause of items disappearing.